# VBA function with array inputs

Tags: vba

I am trying to create a more user friendly version of the function sumproduct but I don't understand why the function is returning #VALUE!. Please advise:

Below is my code both array inputs are of the same length:

```
Function sp(x As Variant, y As Variant) As Double

psum = 0


For i = LBound(x) To UBound(x)
    qsum = x(i) * y(i)
    psum = psum + qsum
Next

sp = psum

End Function
```

Comment: Have you debugged the code and observed how qsum and psum changes?

Comment: The issue is with your data and not the code.  check that.  You probably have text instead of numbers in the arrays you are passing.

Answer (score 1):

You need to state what qsum and psum are. Also make sure the arrays being called in are also of the same type variant.:

```
Function sp(x As Variant, y As Variant) As Double
Dim psum, qsum As Double
psum = 0


For i = LBound(x) To UBound(x)
    qsum = x(i) * y(i)
    psum = psum + qsum
Next

sp = psum

End Function
```

Test sub

```
  Sub test()
    Dim ex, wy As Variant
    ex = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
    wy = Array(2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
    Call sp(ex, wy)

    End Sub
```

This worked for me without the Value Error